# How to avoid NaN in logistic regression?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, logistic-regression

```
function [predictY] = logisticRegressionClassify(testX, testY, w)
    temp = arrayfun(@(x) x/(1+x), exp(testX * w));
    [~, predictY] = max(temp, [], 2);
```

I am running multi-class logistic regression, and never get a reasonable result. Then I found the problem occurs as temp is calculated with NaN and 0. How to modify this code to avoid such problem?

Comment: I suppose the problem lies in the array `testX * w` since everything else looks ok.

Comment: What is the expected range of values of variable x?

Comment: @BudoZindovic exp is always positive. Kinda strange way to write it with arrayfun, but it looks fine to me.

Comment: @MatthewGunn you are right but the first part of the arrayfun is x/(1+x) so I was refereing to this part.

Comment: What's probably happening is testX * w is something like 2000, then exp(2000) = inf, and then it does inf/(1+inf) and returns NaN;

Comment: @brainkz the problem is `exp(x) / exp(x)`  won't be 1 if `x` is sufficiently large

Comment: @MatthewGunn +1, now I see it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Subtle problem! It seems like you're using the correct formula, but then it goes kablooie with numerical problems. Why? `exp(x)/exp(x)` is not equal to 1 if `x` is sufficiently large.

A solution is to use a different but mathematically equivalent formula:

```
temp = arrayfun(@(x) 1/(1+x), exp(-testX * w))
```

You could also drop the `arrayfun` call (it seems unnecessary unless I'm missing something?):

```
temp = 1./(1+exp(-testX*w);
```

These are equivalent formulas to what you wrote (but without the numerical problems). In mathematics, e^x/(1+e^x) = 1/(1+e^-x)

#### What's going wrong with the original version?

Let's assume testX * w = 2000. Then you have exp(2000) = inf, and `exp(2000)/ ( 1+ exp(2000)` returns `NaN` because inf/inf is undefined. On the other hand, 1/inf = 0, and the second formula works nicely in all situations.

To recap:

```
exp(x) ./ ( 1+ exp(x))          % <------ can give you inf/inf= NaN problems
1 ./ ( 1  + exp(-x))            % <------ works great!
```